# excel find keyword and replace all content of columns contains this keyword by another keyword

Tags: excel, replace

Hi i have a file excel(2016) contains address columns 
for example "N02 Street AA City"
 i need to find for example "City" and replace all of content columns "N02 Street AA City" by just "City"
thanks

Comment: It's difficult for me to imagine a solution that doesn't make use of VBA.

Comment: It's difficult for me to imagine how I work for you free of charge.

Comment: To @Variatus point, your experience with this site will be maximized if you first attempt a solution and then show us the attempt along with what about it isn't working as you hoped.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,A2)),B2,A2)
```

the search() function is not case-sensitive, for case-sensitive Searches use the find()-function.

[image: search substitute]